# mpirun is not working with two nodes

Tags: fortran, mpi, fortran90, openmpi, fortran77

I am working in a cluster where each node has 16 processors. My version of Open MPI is
1.5.3. I have written the following simple code in fortran:

```
  program MAIN
  implicit none
  include 'mpif.h'
  integer status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
  integer ierr,my_rank,size


  integer irep, nrep, iex
  character*1 task


  !Initialize MPI
  call mpi_init(ierr)
  call mpi_comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,my_rank,ierr)
  call mpi_comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,size,ierr)


  do iex=1,2

     if(my_rank.eq.0) then
        !Task for the master
        nrep = size

        do irep=1,nrep-1
          task='q'
          print *, 'master',iex,task
          call mpi_send(task,1,MPI_BYTE,irep,irep+1,
 &                     MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
        enddo


     else
        !Here are the tasks for the slaves


        !Receive the task sent by the master node
        call mpi_recv(task,1,MPI_BYTE,0,my_rank+1,
 &                   MPI_COMM_WORLD,status,ierr)


        print *, 'slaves', my_rank,task


     endif

  enddo


  call mpi_finalize(ierr)

  end
```

then I compile the code with:

```
/usr/lib64/openmpi/bin/mpif77 -o test2 test2.f
```

and run it with

```
/usr/lib64/openmpi/bin/mpirun  -np 32 -hostfile nodefile test2
```

my nodefile looks like this:

```
node1
node1
...
node2
node2
...
```

with node1 and node2 repeated 16 times each.

I can compile successfully. When I run it for -np 16 (so just one node) it works 
fine: each slave finishes its task and I get the prompt back in the terminal. But when I try -np 32, not all the slaves finish
their work, only 16 of them.

Actually with 32 nodes the program doesn't give me the
prompt back, so that I think the program is stacked somewhere and is waiting for
some task to be perform.

I would like to receive any comment from you as far as I have spent some time in this
trivial problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that your nodefile is correct.  I'd expect to see lines like this:

```
node1 slots=16
```

OpenMPI is pretty well-documented, have you checked out their FAQ ?

Comment: Actually I have tried several ways to set up the nodes including -host node1,node2. I tried what you said and the behavior is exactly the same I dont get the prompt back.

Answer (score 0):

did you try mpiexec instead of mpirun?